# C static_assert first parameter

Tags: static-assert

I wrote this code to test static_assert

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define static_assert _Static_assert

typedef enum {ONE=1, TWO, THREE} num_t;

uint8_t Is_Num_Valid(num_t number){
uint8_t i = 0;
    for(i=1;i<4;i++){
        if(number == i){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    num_t number;
    number = ONE;
    printf("%d\n", Is_Num_Valid(number));

    if(Is_Num_Valid(number)){
        static_assert(0, "Number entered is out of boundaries");
    }


    printf("Number is> %d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Which always results in a compilation error
error: static assertion failed: "Number entered is out of boundaries"

why this is not working, it should not execute the body of if() if the condition is 0!!!

Comment: i know i can't use a const int with static_assert as it's != constant_expression, thats why i tried to use this method.

Comment: What do you expect if it is not valid? Do you expect a compilation error after successful compilation?

Comment: If you need to evaluate expression at runtime, perhaps you wanted ordinary `assert`, not `static` one? `static_assert(0)` basically instructs compiler to always fail compilation of current translation unit, regardless of where it placed (unless cut out by e.g. preprocessor's `#if`).

Comment: thanks guys for help, i already know the difference between assert and static_assert, but the answer of Daniel H clarified what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `static_assert` happens at compile time, but the decision in an `if` statement happens at run time. The compiler cannot know that the `if` clause will be false, and it needs to look at the body of the `if` statement to know what to do if it isn’t. It sees a static assert, which fails, so generates a compilation error.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now i know why :)